# C# How can I get the number (count) of keys in <configSections>

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I'm trying to get the *number* of configuration sections in my app.Config in order to initialize an int var to this # and read the items in a loop dinamically at run time.

```
<configSections>
  <section name="Section1" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>
  <section name="Section2" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>
  <section name="Section3" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>
</configSections>
```

In this example, the *count* would be 3.

I have tried with ConfigurationSectionGroup and other classes but either their .Count property does not return the correct number (they seem to inherit additional sections/groups from elsewhere) or the class simply doesn't have a Count property.

I may go through the section and count each item to get a # but I wonder if there's a direct method or property to get this # at once.

Thanks.

Comment: Xml config files are a little old-school now, I am not saying what you want to do is impossible, however they are limited. If it were me, id move this to the more modern configuration world of Configuration sources. You could conceivable store everything you want in json and materialize it to concrete classes if need be. at that point you can use any regular C# method to do anything you want

Comment: Thanks but not what is asked or needed. Implementation is already this way and we don't have either the time nor the resources (people, income) to change radically the code. It's just maintenance and my client wouldn't pay for this upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XmlDocument` class.

But first add `System.Xml.XmlDocument` in your project, using NuGet Packages.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configSections>
  <section name="Section1" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>
  <section name="Section2" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>
  <section name="Section3" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>
  <other name="Other" type="ConfigSections.Other, MyNamespace"/>
</configSections>
```

Code example

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(".../test.xml"); //path to xml file

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/configSections/section");
Console.WriteLine(xnList.Count);
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string value = xn.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Result

```
3
Section1
Section2
Section3
```